# Get positions for matching labels from Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Following [How to Retrain an Image Classifier for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining)  I have gotten tensorflow to recognize a few labels that I've tried with, but I notice that when running the provided python-script, I get only the labels and the matching level.

I'm looking to get the position of the labels as well, and I can't see that this information is available in the python-script. I assume it's available somewhere, but that I'd have to use lower level API-calls to achieve this?